# How can I change the format of footnotes in Jekyll's kramdown?

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll

Currently, using kramdown in Jekyll, footnotes using `[^1]` displays a superscripted number as such.<sup>1</sup> However, I wish footnotes to look like this<sup>[1]</sup> in the fashion of Wikipedia.

Where can I find the code to manipulate for this small change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To achieve your goal, you can use css.

If you have something like this in *mypost.md* content :

```
I make a reference to a footnote [^1].
[^1]: This is the footnote
```

Add two css rules :

```
a.footnote:before {   
 content: "[";
}

a.footnote:after {
    content: "]";
}
```

Done !

Comment: Oh wow, thanks! I never knew there was something in CSS that let you append/prepend content to elements! Thanks :D

Comment: If you want to discover the marvel of css I encourage you to bookmark https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS